# jquery datepicker not working on smarty

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

#### link provides

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/assetbox/resources/themes/Charcoal/css/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/assetbox/resources/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/assetbox/resources/javascript/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

#### html tag

```
<div class="box col-6 formfield">
<input type="text" maxlength="50" name="cal" value="" class="" id="datepicker" > 
        </div>

 <script type="text/javascript"> 
            {literal}

            jQuery(function($){
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

            });

            {/literal}
    </script>
```

link where i download: `http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/`

note:-it work fine on localhost but when i use in pixaria(www.pixaria.com)using smarty it dosen't work.

Comment: Are there any errors you can tell us about?

Comment: your path is for `localhost` so it won't work for `www.pixaria.com`. You need to give path relative to your host.

Comment: no it's works fine no localhost.i download it from http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ you can check it out.

Comment: you have any idea regarding pixaria software.any one have any idea regarding pixaria softare.please help me out.

Comment: Looking at your source you missing `<script type="text/javascript">` on nearly all your js includes. Maybe this is issue.

Comment: @Morpheus-where please help me out......

Comment: [translate.google.com](http://translate.google.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        {literal}

        $(function(){
            $( "#ds" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });

        });

        {/literal}
    </script>
```

correction: